React Js With Laravel API Sanctum User Register 419 Error
I am new to react js and am trying to register a new user into my database with my react js frontend using Laravel API Sanctum and I am getting this error:
Request failed with status code 419
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 419
    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80917:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:79599:66)

My UserAPIController.php laravel file
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Models\User;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiV1UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'mobile' => ['required', 'string', 'min:10'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8']
            // 'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed']
        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json(['validation_errors'=>$validator->messages()],422);
        }else{
            $user = User::create([
                'name'=>$request->name,
                'email'=>$request->email,
                'mobile'=>$request->mobile,
                'password'=>Hash::make($request->password),
            ]);
            $token = $user->createToken($user->email.'_Token')->plainTextToken;

            return response()->json([
                "status"=>true,
                "username"=>$user->name,
                "token"=>$token,
                "message"=>"User Registered Succesfully!"
            ],201);
        }
    }
}

My Register.js react file
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useNavigate, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import swal from "sweetalert";
import { aslInterpreting, snowflakeO } from "fontawesome";

function Register() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [registerInput, setRegister] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    mobile: "",
    password: "",
    error_list: [],
  });

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setRegister({ ...registerInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const registerSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      name: registerInput.name,
      email: registerInput.email,
      mobile: registerInput.mobile,
      password: registerInput.password,
    };

    axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
      axios.post(`/api/register`, data).then((res) => {
        if (res.data.status === 201) {
          localStorage.setItem("auth_token", res.data.token);
          localStorage.setItem("auth_name", res.data.username);
          swal("Success", res.data.message, "success");
          navigate("/");
        } else {
          setRegister({
            ...registerInput,
            error_list: res.data.validation_errors,
          });
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <section className="login-box">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-3"></div>
          <div className="col-lg-6">
            <div className="input-box">
              <header>Create Account</header>
              <form onSubmit={registerSubmit}>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.name}
                    name="name"
                    id="name"
                  />
                  <label>Full Name</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.name}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    className="input"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.email}
                    name="email"
                    id="email"
                  />
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.email}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    className="input"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.mobile}
                    name="mobile"
                    id="mobile"
                  />
                  <label>Mobile</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.mobile}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    className="input"
                    onChange={handleInput}
                    value={registerInput.password}
                    name="password"
                    id="password"
                  />
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <span className="text-danger">
                    {registerInput.error_list.password}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div className="ps-2 pb-3">
                  <input type="checkbox" className="me-1" name="" id="" />
                  <Link to="/terms-conditions">
                    Agree to our terms and conditions
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                  <button type="submit" className="login-submit">
                    Register
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
              <div className="signin">
                <div className="signup pb-2">
                  <span>
                    <Link to="/login">Already has an account?</Link>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <span className="pb-2">
                  <Link to="#">Forgot password?</Link>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Register;

And my App.js react file
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";
import axios from "axios";

import "./App.css";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Products from "./components/Products";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://jaano.test";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
axios.defaults.headers.post["Accept"] = "application/json";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I am getting this error in my console

{message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}
exception
:
"Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"
file
:
"D:\xampp\htdocs\jaano\jaanobackend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php"
line
:
389
message
:
"CSRF token mismatch."

Any help?

csrf token error in laravel sanctum API and react js


You need to pass the CSRF header with your axios calls. You can do this using an interceptor.
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const newConfig = config;
    if (cookie.parse(document.cookie)["XSRF-TOKEN"]) {
      newConfig.headers!["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = cookie.parse(document.cookie)[
        "XSRF-TOKEN"
      ];
    }

    return newConfig;
  },
  (err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);

Double check after you've done this that the login / register request is using the XSRF-TOKEN header.

Please where should i place this code that you have writting to me, is it in the App.js file or Register.js file

it should work if you add it underneath your axios.defaults. setters, but how i normally do it is put all my axios config into a file, and export axios. then instead of importing from axios i import from my config file. it avoids setting those values multiple times.

still don't understand, I am new to react js, so if you could explain in details or show it in code , I will be ok.

Example, you can tell me, maybe the code should be pasted in App.js or Register.js file just after this code, so i will know where to paste it and after which code that i have to psate it, since i have posted my codes at above

try it in app.js after this line axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

sorry, i am have a code error underline in red with this code newConfig.headers!, do i need to import something?

The error said i am missing a semicolumn Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: D:\xampp\htdocs\jaano\jaanofrontend\src\App.js: Missing semicolon. (53:23) I don't know whether is is the ! sign or not, please any help?

Could by a typescript or eslint error, try disabling both for that line. Send over your code and i can have a look at the missing semicolon

This is the code

axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
const token = localStorage.setItem("auth_token");
config.headers.Authorization = token ? Bearer ${token} : "";
if (cookie.parse(document.cookie)["XSRF-TOKEN"]) {
config.headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = cookie.parse(document.cookie)[
"XSRF-TOKEN"
];
}
return config;
});

And am getting this error now 'cookie' is not defined  no-undef

Oh sorry, forgot to mention i've used this package to handle cookies, https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie you can import it at the top of your file.

I have install the cookies package in react using npm install cookies and they are saying in the documentation that i should use var cookie = require('cookie'); or var cookies = cookie.parse('foo=bar; equation=E%3Dmc%5E2');
// { foo: 'bar', equation: 'E=mc^2' } hoe do i write it in  my code, and you are saying i should import something what should I import, can you please teach me by typing it in my code above so i could see where the code will be written?

Can you plaese check this error for me, Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:123:30, i am getting this error from my Register.js file, can you please watch the code for me since I am about to sent it after this message and see if there is nay error in the code

The Register.js file is already posted above, so if you please watch and help me identify the error Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present. TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.     at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:123:30.

This is my laravel code fr generating token ` $user = User::create([
'name'=>$request->name,
'email'=>$request->email,
'mobile'=>$request->mobile,
'password'=>Hash::make($request->password),
]);
$token = $user->createToken($user->email.'_Token')->plainTextToken;
        return response()->json([
            "status"=>true,
            "username"=>$user->name,
            "token"=>$token,
            "message"=>"User Registered Succesfully!"
        ],201);`


You need to pass the token when you do this localStorage.setItem("auth_token"); as the second parameter

Don't understand please, in my Register.js file, I have this,

localStorage.setItem("auth_token", res.data.token);           localStorage.setItem("auth_name", res.data.username);

Can you please demonstrate it with a code, because I don't understand it, but if you write in my own code, maybe I will. Thanks

I am installing both the token and username in the local storage of my browser, that is what the code above means localStorage.setItem("auth_token", res.data.token);           localStorage.setItem("auth_name", res.data.username);

Maybe in my App.js I am only getting auth_token, as in this code const token = localStorage.setItem("auth_token");  and they want me to also call or get auth_name also, can you please check my App.js file at above for me

`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
var cookie = require("cookie");
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
const token = localStorage.setItem("auth_token");
config.headers.Authorization = token ? Bearer ${token} : "";
if (cookie.parse(document.cookie)["XSRF-TOKEN"]) {
config.headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = cookie.parse(document.cookie)[
"XSRF-TOKEN"
];
}
return config;
});`

This is my App.js and maybe they want mre to also call or get token auth_name too, any help on my App.js file?

you have not passed the token to setItem, its this line: localStorage.setItem("auth_token"); i think its meant to be localStorage.getItem("auth_token"); thats why you are seeing the error, you should install eslint in your project and it will show you syntax errors like this.

Should I change the code on App.js or Register.js or change it on both files

How should i write it, like this

const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");   config.headers.Authorization = token ? Bearer ${token} : ""; Or?

So how do i write the localStorage code just after the axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; ? Can you please teach me how to write the code?

var cookie = require("cookie");  axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {   const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");   config.headers.Authorization = token ? Bearer ${token} : ""; if (cookie.parse(document.cookie)["XSRF-TOKEN"]) { config.headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = cookie.parse(document.cookie)[ "XSRF-TOKEN" ]; } return config; });

This code is what I have already in my App.js `var cookie = require("cookie");
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
config.headers.Authorization = token ? Bearer ${token} : "";
if (cookie.parse(document.cookie)["XSRF-TOKEN"]) {
config.headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = cookie.parse(document.cookie)[
"XSRF-TOKEN"
];
}
return config;
});that is my code, and I get 419 errorCSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component`

I wish a better place to post all my codes for you to see, this is post my App.js codes, Register.js codes and Login.js codes to see if there is any mistake or errors

Check in your network requests if the XSRF token is present. Also try and clear your site cache as it could have an old value.

This is the error I am getting message :  "CSRF token mismatch."

Are you on any other website platform apart from stack overflow where I can send you my codes for you to check?

I cleared the cache using npm cache clean --force and npm cache verify and still getting the 419 error settle.js:19 Uncaught (in promise)  AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 419', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …} message :  "Request failed with status code 419" name :  "AxiosError" request :

XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …} response :  {data: {…}, status: 419, statusText: 'unknown status', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …} stack :  "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 419\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80222:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78904:66)" [[Prototype]] :  Error

did you check that the XSRF token is in the request by checking your network tab: Right click -> Inspect Element -> Network -> (Make login request to api) -> Network tab headers should have XSRF.

I am not getting XSRF token

Request URL: http://jaano.test/api/login Request Method: POST Status Code: 419 unknown status Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin Accept: application/json Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9 Authorization: Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 49 Content-Type: application/json Host: jaano.test Origin: http://localhost:3000 Referer: http://localhost:3000/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G950U Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/

The code above is what i am getting from my inspect->network->header

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://jaano.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*

The error just above this message is what I am having now, cors error

okay what you need to do is create a new file called axios.js and add the interceptor and at the end of the file export axios, then instead of import axios from 'axios'  you want to import from your axios.js file.

`import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
var cookie = require("cookie");
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
const token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
config.headers.Authorization = token ? Bearer ${token} : "";
if (cookie.parse(document.cookie)["XSRF-TOKEN"]) {
config.headers["X-XSRF-TOKEN"] = cookie.parse(document.cookie)[
"XSRF-TOKEN"
];
}
return config;
});
export default axios;`

This is the code that i have written above, because i have created the axios.js file and cut and paste this code above from App.js to axios.js, and is the code correct? please check. And where do I import the axios.js file to, is it in App.js or Register.js?

Can I please have your email so i can send my React app as zip file for you to check my App.js, Register.js, Login.js and axios.js file? my email is alewa2015@gmail.com.

Please I have just sent you the react folder in your email, can you check the App.js file and also The axios.js, Register.js and Login.js file in components folder, And please teach me how to write the code well. I have not imported the axios.js file yet either in Register.js or App.js, I don't know.

I am getting this error in the console,
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://jaano.test/sanctum/csrf-cookie' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed. But the error on my react.js app is, Network Error Axios Error : Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError.
I have sent you an email for this error, so you can please check you email, any help?

I think its probably best you do some online tutorials and get the basics of react and Laravel covered, once you are familiar with some of the low level concepts you should be able to get this debugged.

Please i just sent you a react code in you email, can you please check if the is any mistake in the code.

Hi sir, just sent you an email for help, in react js
